# angularjs + elasticsearch , input host to connect elasticsearch

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

It's possible to input the host address to connect

elasticsearch? Thanks!!

This is code :

html:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="input.host">
</div>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('submit', ['angular-ladda', 'elasticsearch']);

app.service('client', function (esFactory) {
    return esFactory({
        host: 'localhost:9400',
        apiVersion: '1.2',
        log: 'trace'
    });
});

app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', 'client', 'esFactory', function ($scope, client, esFactory) {
    $scope.input = {
        host: ''
    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it available by putting in a rest service, or just in a file and do a $http request to get the file .

something like `input = $http.get("elasticsearchconfig.json"`).